# Functional Relational Operators, join-like, outside of queries

Tags: linq, f#

Let's say I have two ordered collections of key-value-pairs, and I need to perform an inner equi-join on them to produce pairs of values: `seq<'a * 'b> -> seq<'a * 'c> -> seq<'b * 'c>`.

This is easily enough wired to the extension methods of `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

```
let foo abs acs =
    System.Linq.Enumerable.Join(abs, acs, 
        (fun ab -> fst ab), (fun ac -> fst ac),
        fun ab ac -> snd ab, snd ac )
foo ["A",1;"B",2] ["B",1;"C",2;"B",3]
// val it : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int * int> =
//  seq [(2, 1); (2, 3)]
```

Translation of that functionality to F# is not that straightforward. To avoid filtering on the Cartesian product, I'm probably loosing some laziness/execution on demand.

```
let bar abs acs = 
    let d = dict(Seq.groupBy fst acs) in seq{
        for a, b in abs do
            let ok, cs = d.TryGetValue a
            if ok then for c in cs -> b, snd c }
bar ["A",1;"B",2] ["B",1;"C",2;"B",3]
// val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(2, 1); (2, 3)]
```

Yet it feels crufty, like a hand-forged, bespoke solution to a particular sub-problem. How can I approach [relational operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators), possibly also natural, semi-, anti- or outer joins, in a more general, abstract way?

Comment: What's wrong with using `System.Linq.Enumerable`?

Comment: F# `Seq` module doesn't provide a hash join a la `Enumerable.Join`. Just use the LINQ version if you have to, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a query expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) to achieve the same thing.

```fs
query {
  for a in ["A",1;"B",2] do
  join b in ["B",1;"C",2;"B",3] on (fst a = fst b)
  select (snd a, snd b) };;

val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(2, 1); (2, 3)]
```

Alternatively, there is nothing wrong with just using `System.Linq.Enumerable.Join`.